# Why am I getting the Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a dynamic menu, but I keep getting the fatal error.  Here is the code:

```
class Menu {

public $menu;

function __contstruct() {
    $this -> menu = array("Home" => "index.php",
    //"Eat" => array("Casual" => "casual.php", "Fine dining" => "fine_dining.php"),
    "Contact" => "contact.php");
}

public static function page_name() {
    return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], "/") + 1);
}

public static function menu_list() {
    $menu_list = "";
    foreach ($this->menu as $name => $url) {
        echo "<li ";
        if ($url == $this -> pagename()) {
            $menu_list .= "class='active'";
        }
        $menu_list .= "><a href='";
        $menu_list .= $url;
        $menu_list .= "'>" . $name . "</a></li>";
        return ($menu_list);
    }
}

}
?>
```

and calling it with

```
$nav = new Menu();
echo $nav->menu_list();
```

Please help me figure why it isn't working.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: You've got multiple typos anyways. `$this->pagename()` does not exist. you've got `$this->page_name()` defined.

Comment: `__contstruct()` <= **look closely.** Zoom in if you have to. Better yet, look inside a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `$this` in a static method.  `$this` is for objects.  Use `self` to refer to the class a method is contained in when you don't have an instance.

Remove `static` from you method signature if you want to use in object context.

And more importantly, you spelled 'construct' incorrectly and typed 'pagename' instead of 'page_name'.  This works:

```
<?php

class Menu {

public $menu;

function __construct() {
    $this -> menu = array("Home" => "index.php",
    //"Eat" => array("Casual" => "casual.php", "Fine dining" => "fine_dining.php"),
    "Contact" => "contact.php");
}

public function page_name() {
    return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], "/") + 1);
}

public function menu_list() {
    $menu_list = "";
    foreach ($this->menu as $name => $url) {
        echo "<li ";
        if ($url == $this -> page_name()) {
            $menu_list .= "class='active'";
        }
        $menu_list .= "><a href='";
        $menu_list .= $url;
        $menu_list .= "'>" . $name . "</a></li>";
        return ($menu_list);
    }
}

}

$nav = new Menu();
echo $nav->menu_list();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That works perfectly.  I'm trying to get the handle of OOP and this is my project to do it with.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @user2367438 Please mark as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark.  An upvote is always nice, too = )

Comment: Not enough rep for an upvote, but it will be accepted.  Thanks again